# "'tuple' object is not callable" when attempting to plot

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, plot, tuples, iris-dataset

Quite new to Python and I'm trying to plot the training set of the Iris Classification dataset, however when attempting to plot I get the error "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable".

Here's the code:

```py
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)

X = iris["data"][:,(2,3)] # using just two features petal len + wdth
y = iris["target"]

# Plotting 

plt.figure(figsize=(11,4)) # error here

# training examples
plt.plot(X[:, 0][y==1], X[:, 1][y==1], "bs") # iris versicolor
plt.plot(X[:, 0][y == 2], X[:, 1][y==2], "yo") # iris virginica
```

I've set `return_X_y = False` (`return_X_y` returns a tuple if set to `True`) so I'm not quite sure why I'm getting a tuple error, especially at `plt.figure(figsize=(11,4))`Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It runs fine for me

Comment: Did you mess up the `plt.figure` function?

Comment: Your code is working. If you use *tuple*, you must change your code for tuples e.g. this style `iris["data"]` is not executable when *iris* is tuple.